# Showing a given vector bundle is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have an infinite sequence of points $\cdots < x_{-1} < x_0 < x_1 < \cdots$ on the real line and an open cover given by $\{ U_i \}$, where $U_i = (x_i, x_{i + 2})$, and say $E$ is a rank 1 vector bundle on $\mathbb{R}$ which has a trivialization over the $U_i$. I want to show that $E$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle.

This is a homework problem: the method outlined is to show that the cocycle associated to the trivialization over $\{ U_i \}$ is cohomologous to the cocycle which is constantly 1 on each (nonempty) intersection, and I really have no idea how to start. The hint is that we ought to construct functions $h_i : U_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ which "correct" the local trivializations, starting with $i = 0$ and proceeding inductively outward, but I can't even find how to construct such an $h_0$. Any advice would be great!